# Matlab For loop won't stop

Tags: matlab, for-loop

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong with this loop? `P` keeps looping. I just want to stop at `mstlength` which is 11.

```
for l=1:mstlength
l = mst(l,1);
 for p=1:mstlength
    p = mst(p,2)
       plot([nodes(l,2) nodes(p,2)],[nodes(l,3) nodes(p,3)],'k.-')
       hold on
  end
end
```

Thank you

Comment: You are changing the values of loop variables `l` and `p` inside the outer and inner `for` loop. You probably don't want to do this.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is the one stated? I would start by printing the value of `mstlength` before the loop and then use counters to to find out how many times I actually run the loops. If this does not look good I would continue by using the [debugger](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/debugging-code.html)

Answer (score 7):

If you stop bothering the looping variables *inside* the loop, they will stop pestering your loops. :-)

```
    axes();
    hold('on');
    for l=1:mstlength
            vl = mst(l,1);
            for p=1:mstlength
                    vp = mst(p,2);
                    plot([nodes(vl,2) nodes(vp,2)],[nodes(vl,3) nodes(vp,3)],'k.-');
            end;
    end;
```

Comment: @user3510865 I don't want to sound patronizing, but you're plotting 11x11 = 121 graphs, one for each combination of indices `l` and `p`. Is this what you mean by "`p` keeps looping" and "having the same thing"? If yes, what combinations of indices `l` and `p` you'd like to display?